# Electrophilic addition to benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, resonance, c-x-addition

A question deals with electrophilic addition to the following compound;

[image]

Apparently, the benzylic carbon gets a positive charge during electromerism, invoking resonance stabilization.

Benzene is an electron-withdrawing group, and therefore a negative charge on this carbon atom should be stable, as it has resonance stabilisation to boot.

Why isn't this so?

Comment: Is this 1‐phenyl‐1‐propene? If so, does the question specifies whether it's a *cis* or *trans* isomer? Please note that adding proper name for the compounds helps future visitors a lot. Also, please avoid using a [tag:homework] tag: it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an electrophillic reaction. These reactions make cationic intermediates. There's never been a question about stabilizing intermediate carbanions in electrophillic reactions. Thus, you are talking about apples and oranges. Please correct that part in your question.

Now, let's talk about relavent chemistry on electrophillic reactions. The alkene (electron donor) reacts with the electrophilic (electron seeking) proton to make the stable carbocation following Markovnikov's rule. In this case the more stable carbocation will be the carbocation adjacent to the benzene ring, a benzylic carbocation. The benzylic carbocation is more stable than secondary carbocation, because the adjacent benzene ring can stabilize the $\ce{C+}$ center through resonance as depicted in following scheme:

[image: Hydrobromination]